# Contact Form 7 If Condition

Tags: functions, redirect, forms, plugin-contact-form-7, contact

I have used the following code to successfully redirect a form to an URL after submission using contact form 7.

```
<add_action( 'wp_footer', 'redirect_cf7' );

function redirect_cf7() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
   if ( '947' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { // Sends sumissions on form 947 to the first thank you page
    location = 'https://www.example.com/thank-you-1/';
    } else if ( '1070' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { // Sends submissions on form 1070 to the second thank you page
        location = 'https://www.example.com/thank-you-2/';
    } else { // Sends submissions on all unaccounted for forms to the third thank you page
        location = 'https://www.example.com/thank-you-3/';
    }
}, false );
</script>
<?php
}
```

Can this be modified to redirect once a certain field contains a certain value (for example [Post-Code] Contains KA7) and another field contains a value (for example [Bedrooms] == 1) ?

Thanks in advance

Andy

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able access the form fields and field values with `event.detail.inputs` in `addEventListener` on `wpcf7mailsent`. You can then use the field values in the conditional statements and add the redirects you need. There's a simple code sample in the plugin doumentation, https://contactform7.com/dom-events/, for looping the fields.

**EDIT**
Here's a code example,

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {

  var inputs = event.detail.inputs,
      inputCount = inputs.length,
      firstCondition,
      secondCondition;

  for ( var i = 0; i < inputCount; i++ ) {
    if ( 'first-condition-field' == inputs[i].name ) {
      firstCondition = inputs[i].value
    } else if ( 'second-condition-field' == inputs[i].name ) {
      secondCondition = inputs[i].value
    }
  }

  if ( 'foo' == firstCondition && 'bar' == secondCondition ) {
    location = 'https://www.example.com/thank-you-1/';
  } else if ( 'bar' == firstCondition && 'baz' == secondCondition ) {
    location = 'https://www.example.com/thank-you-2/';
  }

}, false );
```

Comment: But i am looking at using 2 fields to determine an out come so would i still use the following?

Comment: document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
    var inputs = event.detail.inputs;
 
    for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
        if ( 'your-name' == inputs[i].name ) {
            alert( inputs[i].value );
            break;
        }
    }
}, false );

Comment: Something like that. I added a code example to my answer.

Comment: Amazing Antti, thanks you for this, i will give this a go.

Comment: Would i put this into functions.php in contact form 7 plugin?

Comment: No, you need to put that into your (child) theme's scripts.js file. Another option is to echo a script tag with a custom function, which is attached to wp_footer action. This function should be put to your (child) theme's functions.php file. Or if all this sounds like gibberish to you, use any add-scrpits-to-your-site plugin found in the WP plugin repository.